# SQL script required for number of days between two dates and update string for negative value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have developed below script to calculate Lead time between two dates. But it’s giving incorrect results or missing few orders while running. But when I rerun this, it gives correct result. Is there any other way to calculate number of days between two dates or you see any error there.

GROSS_LEAD_TIME is nvarchar. First update gives integer & second update gives string.

```
Update TABLE1  
Set GROSS_LEAD_TIME =  DATEDIFF(DAY,  dbo.TRUNC_DATE([CREATE DATE]),dbo.TRUNC_DATE([TIME STAMP]))
Where [TIME STAMP] is not null and [CREATE DATE] is not null

Update TABLE1  
Set GROSS_LEAD_TIME = 'Negative LT CD Gt TS'
Where  dbo.trunc_date([Create Date]) >  dbo.trunc_date([TIME STAMP]) and [TIME STAMP] is not null 
and [Create Date] is not null
```

Trunc Date is devloped function which ignores time part.

Sample Data >>>

[image]

Comment: You first set `GROSS_LEAD_TIME` to a `int` and then in the second query a `varchar`? Why are you mixing data types? This feels like a design flaw to start with. Why have a function that "ignores the time part"? What's wrong with the `date` datatype that has no time portion? Even so, `DATEDIFF(DAY, '20200101', '20200520')` and `DATEDIFF(DAY,'2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000', '2020-05-20T23:59:59.9999999')` return the same value (`140`) so the time part isn't even considered anyway. Sample data and expected results will also help us help you here, as your logic appears to be quite flawed.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `TRUNC_DATE` and examples of values eg `CREATE DATE]`, `[TIME STAMP]` - can't say much. `GROSS_LEAD_TIME` should be `int` if it represents a number of days. There has to be a better way. Consider posting the table structure, show some values and give a concrete example of expected result.

Comment: @Larnu , I agree , I can ignore trunc date. But use of two data types is required. I need to flag orders with negative leadtime. Sample Data attached.